# How to write join query in wso2 DSS

Tags: join, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I have two tables upon which i want to implement join and get data. My Table1 has two columns as
 Table1:
ID and Table1Description

Table 2 Has three columns as:
ID,Table2Description  and Table1_ID

My join query is:

```
Select t1.ID,t1.Table1Description,t2.ID,t2.Table2Description from Table t1
join Table2 t2 on t1.ID=t2.Table1_ID
```

Now my only problem is how to create output mapping for both ID's uniquely?

Looking forward to your answers.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update retrieval of t2.ID with 't2.ID as ID2' to assign it to ID2. Then you can use two unique output field names for ID columns.

```
 <query id="q1" useConfig="s1">
  <sql>Select t1.ID,t1.Table1Description,t2.ID as ID2,t2.Table2Description from Table1 t1 join Table2 t2 on t1.ID=t2.Table1_ID</sql>
  <result element="Entries" rowName="Entry">
     <element column="ID" name="ID1" xsdType="string"/>
     <element column="Table1Description" name="Table1Description" xsdType="string"/>
     <element column="ID2" name="ID2" xsdType="string"/>
     <element column="Table2Description" name="Table2Description" xsdType="string"/>
  </result>
```